# File upload in Moodle using jmeter

Tags: file, jmeter, upload, load-testing, moodle

I'm busy setting up a load test for file upload in moodle and I am struggling with the file upload. It seems to be losing the sesskey when it gets to the uploading of the file.

Here is the error message from the response data:

"{"error":"A required parameter (sesskey) was missing","errorcode":"missingparam","stacktrace":null,"debuginfo":null,"reproductionlink":null}".

Please help, this test needs to be done in the next 2 days.

Thank you in advance.

I extracted the sesskey using the Regular Expression Extractor and this worked for downloading a file and taking a quiz in moodle but for file upload it loses the session.

Answer (score 0):

Just record the file upload event using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), the only thing you will need to do is to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation prior to starting the file upload in the browser, this way JMeter will be able to properly capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.

Once you have recorded "skeleton" you can [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the dynamic values like `sesskey`